# App hangs on relaunch after killing it in multitasker

Tags: ios7

I'm having the aforementioned problem with my app. It happens whether I use the simulator or an iOS device. Basically, I will close the app, double-click the home button to bring up the recent apps, and remove my app from there. Right after I do that in the simulator, Xcode comes into focus with this:
[image: Screen after ending app]
When I click on the app icon to launch the app again, the simulator/device freezes and does not respond to home button clicks.

I'm not sure why this happens at all. Is there something I must do when the user kills the app from the recent apps? Please enlighten me.

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forcibly killing the app in the device/simulator while it is still running in Xcode. Xcode doesn't like that. So don't do that. But it doesn't indicate *anything* about your app when it is out in the field; the problem arises only because the app was launched *through Xcode*, and that is not how the user is going to run it.

Comment: Also I would ask you "why are you doing that in the first place"? To stop the app, stop it _in Xcode_, not by killing it from the multitasking interface in the device/simulator.

Comment: The thing is, it happens on an actual device as well. The app will hang on relaunch. That's why I'm not sure what to do. Am I missing anything in main.m?

Comment: No, it's the same answer. It's happening on the actual device, but you are killing the app when you launched it _on the device from Xcode_. Don't do that.

Comment: If you pull the plug out of your computer and just run the app on your device, no problem, you can kill and relaunch it all you like. - Again I ask you why you are behaving in this odd way. Is it because you are trying to test automatic saving-and-restoration? If so, that's not how to do it.

Comment: I'm not testing saving and restoration. Just trying to see if the app will hang. I will test it out again on an actual device, without it being plugged in. I remembered it happens as well.

Comment: It seems that I remembered wrongly. I must have tested the device with it plugged in and launched from Xcode. Thanks so much matt.